# Computer can no longer see Arduino; possibly burned out?

Tags: arduino, usb, serial

I have an Arduino UNO R3. I was working on [this excercise](http://www.oomlout.com/oom.php/products/ardx/circ-04) and I could not get the servo working. I thought the USB port may not provide enough power, so I plugged a 9V/1A adapter into the barrel jack as well. I also pressed the reset button. I noticed the edge of the PCB between the USB port and the barrel jack getting hot, and I unplugged the Arduino.

When I plug the USB cable in now, the "L" and "ON" LEDs light up, but there is no activity on the RX/TX LEDs and my computer does not recognize the Arduino (no /dev/ttyACM0 shows up). Looking at the edge of the PCB, I see a bit of a white powdery residue where it was heating up, although I am not sure if that was there before.

I'm worried that I may have burned something out in the PCB. I may have had the 3 pin header for the servo misaligned. Can anyone offer me some insight into what may have happened?

EDIT: Here is the edge of the board:

[image: Arduino.]

Sorry, I've already scraped off a bit of the powdery stuff, so it is harder to see now.

Comment: What do you mean the edge of the PCB? Can you show a picture of your board?

Comment: If you cooked something it is likely the fuse, a trace, or a the regulator so potentially fixable.  Next time don't try to power a servo or other motor through the arduino, but rather use a separate supply for motors vs logic.

Comment: The board as a PTC, which should have helped somewhat but might need replacement.

Comment: Gustavo, what is a PTC?

Comment: Also, the Arduino does still power on over USB, it just no longer presents an interface to the computer (if that makes sense).

Comment: Do you get an unknown usb device in device manager or it's equivalent?  What do you measure on the 5v and 3.3v pins of the shield headers?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't get any new USB devices showing up (using lsusb in Linux). Unfortunately, I don't have a multimeter to check the pins, but I can power an LED from the 5V and 3.3V headers (it is slightly dimmer using 3.3V).

Comment: The USB hub will generally disable itself if an over-current condition is detected. Try rebooting which will re-enable the USB hub, and see if your computer recognizes the Arduino then. For future reference, power the servo (and other motors) from a separate power supply other than your USB port.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible that you fried the fuse or the regulator on it. To verify that you can use a multimeter. There is a regulator which looks like this:

[image]

You can see if the pins are short(which means it might be busted). 
You should never power a servo as mentioned above by Chris, as it can draw too much current. 
If the regulator is fried, you should give it a shot to replace it, instead of spending money for another one. 
ALso try connecting it to another laptop to see if it is detectable.

Comment: If I fried the regulator, would the Arduino still turn on? It seems to work normally in every way except that it can no longer be programmed by my computer. I have also tried another laptop with the same results.

Comment: To Check if the Regulator is fried, take a multimeter, and see what output voltage you get  GND and Vout. You can see the datasheet of that regulator here: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/12048/ONSEMI/MC33269D-5.0.html   . If you are getting a 5V output, then it might be your current surge protector. Since you see the led turning on it might be something else.

Comment: @ajduff574: Just buy a few parts and fix it. It can't be programmed so its not that useful

Comment: But before that, definitely know what part is not working.

Comment: I don't believe that regulator is involved when the arduino is powered from USB.

Comment: Oh Yes, that is correct. because you already get a 5V from the USB.Try the surge protector(fuse) , and see if the ends are shorted(indicating a working fuse).

Comment: When powering the Arduino with the barrel jack, I can light an external LED via pin 9 (it pulses via PWM, since the servo code that is still loaded was supposed to sweep). How can I check the surge protector?

Comment: The fuse looks like this:   http://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/images/arduino/duemilanove_skp_fuse.jpg

Comment: Ah, on the Uno that is right on the edge where the board was getting hot, so that makes sense. I'm still wondering how its failure only prevents the board from being programmed, though.

Comment: @Sherby I'm pretty sure now that it isn't the fuse. The board seems to be powered fine (I can light an LED using either the barrel jack or USB power). Looking at the schematic, the fuse is inline only with the USB power pins. It's just programming the device that doesn't work.